# Problems of using srand() in libraries

Tags: c++, c, random, software-design

There is a wide use of `srand()/rand()` calls in 3rd party libraries, with predefined seeds. The problem arises when combining different libraries in the same process. Sometimes it's hard to ensure the right sequence of calls, a mix of `srand()` and `rand()` calls is possible. Another problem is inability to choose seeding value on application level. As a general rule, should we **avoid using `srand()` in libraries** (including Open Source), leaving the task of seeding to applications?

Comment: *Or* you could use a random API designed in this century, which doesn't rely on a single *global* seed. Really, `rand()` is a horrible broken, badly designed and badly implement API. If your library needs a random generator, use a decent one, which doesn't mess with the global state of the process.

Comment: From application designer's POV, srand() in open-source libraries is my problem. We even don't need security-grade randomness.

Comment: every decent library out there should rely on the actual user to call srand(). If you use 3rd party stuff where srand() is called, please tell them that this is very bad practice and make the world a better place :)

Comment: @jalf It's a shame that there is no downvote for comments, really. rand() is not a broken API, it's just badly abused.

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin. Zlib, SSL, UPNP etc calls srand(). Awareness of this problem exists, this code is from ffmpeg:  #undef  srand
#define srand srand_is_forbidden_due_to_state_trashing_use_av_lfg_init

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin: it is broken, because it relies on a single, global seed, which means it is not thread-safe, and which means that you cannot instantiate multiple random generators. It is broken because the typical implementation of it is generally very shoddy and all but random, and because anyone expecting anything approaching a normal distribution from it will be sorely disappointed. Really, what would you say is *not* broken about it? A badly designed API, making incorrect usage easy and correct usage hard, coupled with a bad implementation which trips up what *should* be correct usage.

Comment: If it makes you feel better, I could agree to calling it "crappy" instead of broken. But the point remains, you should use one of the much superior alternatives. Like `std::random` for C++. Or the OS-provided ones, like `/dev/urand`, or OpenSSL's implementation, or...

Comment: @jalf - "relies on a single, global seed" has nothing to do with thread safety. Those of us who actually implement standard libraries know how to deal with this sort of issue. Not to mention writing **good** implementations. Yes, `rand()` has a bad reputation; no, it doesn't have to be done badly.

Comment: @PeteBecker: you're right it doesn't have to be done badly, but the implementations I've seen have more than justified the bad reputation. I'm curious about what you mean re. thread safety though. How does having shared global state for all rand() calls not impact thread safety?

Comment: @jalf - shared global state among multiple threads can be managed safely. That's what synchronization primitives are for. What "safety" issues do you think are present with `rand()`?

Comment: @PeteBecker: oh sure, by slapping mutexes around them, which cripples performance (if there's contention, anyway). But you still have the problem the OP complains about, other, unrelated code changing the state of your random generator, which can trip up your code if you expect any kind of determinism. It's just a terrible API/contract, regardless of the quality of the implementation

Comment: @jalf - so when you claimed that `rand()` posed **safety** issues you didn't mean it. Oh, incidentally, there are much better implementation techniques for this synchronization than mutexes. But that doesn't fit in your world, does it?

Comment: @PeteBecker: I don't believe I said that it "posed safety issues", so thanks for playing yourself. :) I said "it is not thread-safe", which is technically incorrect. (Well, in C++98 it *could* legally be implemented in a non-threadsafe manner). What I actually *meant*, and should have said, is that it is implemented so that you need additional synchronization to make it thread-safe, which is an added unnecessary cost. The algorithm specified by the standard (use shared global state) is not thread-safe, so implementers have to work around that.

Comment: @PeteBecker: I'm sorry if I offended you, but I'm really not sure what I did. I said that the quality of implementation of that function is typically poor, which is true of the implementations I've looked at. I can't speak for your implementation, which might well be excellent, but even then, it is still limited by the basically broken contract it is specified by. None of that is meant as an attack on *your* implementation, and I apologize if it was perceived as such.

Comment: @PeteBecker and yes, I am aware of the various forms of synchronization available. I know about futexes, I know about the CAS instruction and its ilk, I know that a good implementation is effectively free as long as there is no contention. But it is still synchronization that would be unnecessary if the specification didn't needlessly mandate shared state.

Comment: Nonetheless, I apologize for stepping on your toes, and it's pretty clear that you're not interested in discussing this civilly. Once again, my apologies. I didn't mean to offend anyone. Have a nice day. :)

Comment: @jalf - neither the C standard nor the C++ standard has never **specified** an algorithm for `rand()`. C89 gave a sample implementation marked as an **example**. Examples are not normative.

Comment: @PeteBecker once again, I'm not sure what your beef is. Are you just nitpicking to show your superiority? I have *a lot* of respect for your work, and you really really don't need to prove to me how "right" you are. But now you're really just nitpicking. When I said "algorithm", I even pointed out the relevant part in parentheses: it is specified as using shared state across all threads (and please correct me if I'm wrong on that). I know that it doesn't specify much else about the algorithm (which is why I said above that the quality of implementation varies and matters)

Comment: But once again, I'm sorry to have inadvertently insulted you, and I have no interest in digging the hole I'm apparently in any deeper. So I'd like to end this discussion here.

Answer (score 1):

For the reasons you mentioned, among others, it's better practice in real life applications to use `boost::random` or C++11 `random` library

Comment: C++11 randomness is great, I agree, but 3rd party libraries manage randomness by itself with srand() calls.

Comment: I can't find any source confirming that boost::random uses srand/rand. Can you supply a reference to this claim?

Comment: There is no problem with boost::random. There is a problem with many other open-source libraries, for example ZLIB.

Answer (score 0):

If the library uses hardcoded seeds, then yes, you SHOULD have a way to change those seeds to something you declare as "random enough" to be a seed.

Also if you are using a platform that has something like /dev/urand, you probably could use that, or if you have to be multiplatform why not use something like OpenSSL's random number library? OpenSSL should probably be available on every platform you are targeting and often it is already installed, so you just need to link it.

Comment: In this situation, the only way is to modify the 3rd party libraries. It complicates easy movement to new versions.

Comment: @DavidKhosid Then why not change the library if it is written badly?

Comment: Practically, we need to search every 3rd party library for this design flaw (objdump), modify the library for every version we bring into the project. I prefer libraries don't call srand() unconditionally.